# What should be done with tags similar to "d6," "d7"?

Tags: discussion, tags

[d6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d6) was used in a [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/6800/1). What should be done with such tags?

- made synonym of the respective version tags currently used
- blocked, so that nobody could use them as tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove it for now. If it recurs naturally, take further action.

Answer (score 1):

These tags have resurfaced again, most have been changed to the correct tags, but I proposed they be made synonyms of [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6) and [7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7)

Comment: I noticed; when I could, I changed them to "7," but we cannot keep editing a question to change "d7" to "7." Probably, to make them synonyms is the better thing to do; blocking them is excessive, as there are tags that should be instead used, while tags should be blocked when there are no tags that can replace the erroneously used ones.