# Create a synonym for the "d6" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

It seems that [d6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d6) is back.
There are currently 7 questions tagged with it. Can we make it a synonym of [6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6)?

The older question is [What should be done with tags similar to "d6," "d7"?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387/what-should-be-done-with-tags-similar-to-d6-d7)

Comment: The number of questions using that tag is now 9. The number is going to slowly increase, and I am starting to get worried about that, for the fact there is a bigger problem around this smaller problem.

Comment: I agree... It's common parlance to use 'D6' and 'D7' over on Drupal.org, a (pair of) synonyms is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is done. I approved the d6 to 6 synonym.